# How can I create random noise that is seamless across modular game assets?

Tags: textures

Does anyone know how I can create a texture for a modular tile, such that when the tiles are arranged, random weathering effects such as scratches will be continuous across seams?

An example photo below shows the ideal result. The scratches are continuous between different tiles. Is creating weathering effects like this possible using any procedural software?

[image]

Comment: You might want to check out Wang tiling.

Answer (score 2):

A tough one. Let's try.

1. Let noise be your (infinite) noise  function.
2. Let Seam_noise be a seamless noise  function in the dimension of your tiles. ([here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/838511/Procedural-seamless-noise-texture-generator) is an example , you can download c# code with a seamless perlin noise implementation )
   Follow an example of seamless perlin repeated 4X4 times (the red quad is your tile dimension)
   [image]
3. Consider a "filter" function like this [image]
4. and the "inverted filter" [image]
5. Multiply (2) and (3) and you get something like : [image]
6. multiply (1) and (4) and get the noise smothed in the borders
7. Mix (5) and (6) and get something like (image zoomed x2): 
   [image]

As you can see is far away from your sample image. You can work on noise quality, in the grid intensity, in the mix function to refine things a bit.